# What are some methods to write scalable services when using a SQL Server 2000 table as a queue of work?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2000, queue

If I have a SQL server 2000 database table I'm using as a queue of work to be performed, what are the best methods for doing that work in a scalable way?  The scenario: There is a windows service which is going to perform some, potentially long running, work for each row in a table.  When only one service is running it's easy to grab the top 10 or 100 rows, perform the work (even in a multi threaded manner) and then update those 10 or 100 rows to say the work is done.  If I want to run that same service on 2 servers I need a locking mechanism so the services aren't grabbing the same rows.  My initial thoughts would be to add a field on the table which indicates that row is locked while work is being performed, so the service would update this "locked" field until the work is done and when selecting a group of rows to work on would make sure the rows are not locked.

Is this the best way to handle this type of work or is it possible to use database level row locking to do the same?  I'm aware that a more ideal solution would likely be message queueing, but let's assume I want to use a database table for the queue of work.  Also it's been suggested this type of thing is much more straightforward in the Oracle world where database level row locking would be the solution, I've not had great luck with using row locking on SQL Server 2000, but may be missing something.

Update: Added tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do choose to go with a database table instead of a message queue framework, you could use the following pattern:

Add a column for owning worker to your queue table. When a worker looks for new work, it could query the queue table for next job in queue with worker column null:

```
SELECT TOP 1 JobId, JobData FROM Queue WHERE Worker IS NULL ORDER BY QueueTime
```

Then the worker can try to claim ownership of the job by executing an update statement:

```
UPDATE Queue SET Worker = 'workerid' WHERE JobId = 'jobid' AND Worker IS NULL
```

If no rows are affected by this update statement, the worker can assume that another worker beat it to claiming ownership and thus move on to the next job. If the worker succeeds in updating the worker column, it can do the work.

You should also keep track of crashing or hanging worker threads and reset the worker column for jobs claimed by a hanging or crashed worker. These jobs will then be picked up by other workers. Note that this implies that jobs need to be designed so that they can be retried. Keeping track of hanging or crashing workers can be accomplished with having workers ping a worker table at regular intervals.